# Selective Installation of Office 365 Apps

Tags: office365

When installing Office 365 for Mac (as shown below), is it possible to install selective apps? For e.g. I don't want Outlook or OneNote.

[image]

Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official statement](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/can-i-do-a-custom-install-of-individual-office-suite-applications-1eede13d-3426-40cc-b30b-9aa40226bb9e)
by Microsoft says that Office products are bundled since Office 2013,
the only way to selectively install is to buy the products individually
on the Microsoft Store.

It is still possible to do a selective install, although this is not simple.
The information is contained in the Microsoft article
[Configuration options for the Office Deployment Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/configuration-options-for-the-office-2016-deployment-tool?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fd3879f0d-766c-469c-9440-0a9a2a905ca8),
which is done by a crafted configuration XML file.

Microsoft has thoughtfully wiped out most mentions of this option, but in this
[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNHyHnedY4E)
a Microsoft employee actually shows the XML required to add Visio and Project
to a Pro Plus 365 2016 CTR installation he is customizing, which is:

[image]

A detailed discussion of this method is found in the article
[Customize Microsoft Office Click-to-Run (C2R) Setup to Install Selected Programs Only](https://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-microsoft-office-click-to-run-c2r-setup-to-install-selected-programs-only/).

For a real-life story of how one person got it to work for him, see the accepted
answer in the post
[Installing Only Particular Office 365 programs?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-office_install/installing-only-particular-office-365-programs/9ebb27d4-1084-42e7-b84a-c5dd76e9232c)

Comment: Folow the guide on `www.askvg.com`, if you have the "Couldn’t install" error, verify the configuration file syntax. For me, I have to replace the quotation mark.