# Can I install Outlook Mail app on windows server 2019?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-server

This app comes with windows 10 as standard. I'd like to install it onto windows server 2019. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is try, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need an installation file for Outlook. Microsoft only supplies
an installation file for Office, which you can get from
[Use the Office offline installer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-office-offline-installer-f0a85fe7-118f-41cb-a791-d59cef96ad1c).

You will require a license key for the installation.
If you don't have one, you will need to buy it.

If you only want to install Outlook, see my answer in the post
[Selective Installation of Office 365 Apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1374688/selective-installation-of-office-365-apps).

Comment: Isn't that for the full outlook as part of office? I'm referring to the outlook that ships with windows 10

Comment: There is no Outlook that ships with Windows, perhaps you mean Windows Mail. You may install on Windows Server the Desktop Experience feature which will bring in some Windows client features. Windows Mail used to be one of the features.

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook Mail app cannot be installed on Windows Server. However, you can access it through a web browser.